# How can I save sweet from ants without refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety, cleaning, sweeteners

Sometimes when I don't have refrigerator, I didn't save sweet from ants. How can I save sweet things from ants without refrigerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how big your package of sweets is, you might be able to get a sort of "moat" around it. Put it in a dish of water, but on/in a second containment to keep the water off the sweets themselves. My husband does this with the jar of honey and it works great. I guess ants don't like to swim.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to place them in something ants can't get into. A box, jar, or sealed plastic bag should to the trick. Note that as @joe points out in the comments, whatever you use has to seal tightly, and the plastic bags have to be thick.

Comment: From experience -- ants can get into boxes unless you tape them shut (and possibly corners and seams, too).  And you need thicker plastic bags, thin ones aren't always enough.  I prefer jars or plastic containers with tight fitting lids.